# Priority on GUI over timers C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, timer

I have a Forms application with multiple Timers in it, all doing there task at different times, but I have now started to have problems with my application on "not so good"-computers. My problem is that the GUI is not geting the time it needs i seems. Just a simple buttonclick with a very minor task can take quite long time. And I feel that its the "push" itself that gets delayd. So now to my question, is there a way to proiritise the GUI over the timers? For example skip a tick if the GUI needs to work? (No timer is that importent that it cant skip sometime). Or is there an other way to allways let the GUI work?
Btw im using `System.Timers.Timer`, is that the right choise over ex System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), if you're using WinForms.

> This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must be used in a window.

It doesn't really matter if you have 1 or 100 timers in your application. What matters is what you are doing in the timer callbacks (the `Tick` handler).  Any code that takes more than a "tiny bit" of time is going to cause a "sluggish" feel to your UI.

If you can elaborate on what all of your timers are doing, and post some code, I can provide further advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use threads

Create new(separate) thread, that will not disturb the timers and your tasks will be completed simultaneously.

But if you are processing complex data, wait for all threads to finish, and then proceed further!!

I hope this will help :)

Comment: If I start a Thread inside the timers, is it just to start it upp and close it when its done?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, those "no so good" computers have just not enough resources to process your tasks in short time. Therefore, you need a multithreading.

Its not so hard as it sounds, just read some [tutorials](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=8v62B2nZi3w4U9RB0ExMzg&cp=26&gs_id=2a&xhr=t&q=C%23+multithreading+tutorial&es_nrs=true&pf=p&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&oq=C%23+multithreading+tutorial&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bGE&fp=8c6deed726f743b1&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=979) and voila.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start some lenghty task in your timer event, it is better done in a separate thread. The shorthest/simplest way is something like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => { 
    // Do lenghty stuff
    // ...
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {
       // Update UI, if necessary
    });
});
```

I am not a big fan of `System.Timers.Timer` personally. I prefer `System.Threading.Timer` if my tasks are long and/or non-gui, and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` for short GUI updates (it fires on GUI thread, so no need to `Invoke` anything).

One problem with starting tasks on a strictly periodic timer is that it fires, and fires, and fires... even if your previously started tasks are still not complete (unless you stop/start it or some such). The `System.Threading.Timer` is convenient in a way that you can start it to fire once, then, after the task is started *and completed*, start it to fire once again.

```
finally {
    new System.Threading.Timer((o) => { ... }, null, 60000, 0);
}
```